# prove that sum of perimeters of APQ,BRS,CTV is equal to perimeter of ABC

Tags: circles, tangent-line

**Question** -

ABC is a triangle.PQ,RS,TV are tangents to incircle parallel to BC,CA,AB respectively. prove that sum of perimeters of APQ,BRS,CTV is equal to perimeter of ABC ...

**My try** -

So first I cancel common sides and wanted to prove that PQ+RS+TV=PR+ST+VQ

But not able to use the given condition that tangents are parallel to corresponding sides...

Any help will be greatly helpful..
Thanks

Source : CTPCM Olympiad book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X, Y, Z$ be the points where the incircle touches $BC, AC, AB$ respectively, and $K, L, M$ the points where the incircle touches the tangents $PQ, RS, TV$, respectively. Now, note that: $PK=PZ, QK=QY, RZ=RL, SX=SL, TX=TM, VM=VY$, so:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}PQ+RS+TV&=&(PK+QK)+(RL+SL)+(VM+TM)\\&=&PZ+QY+RZ+SX+VY+TX\text{ (as per above equalities)}\\&=&(PZ+RZ)+(SX+TX)+(QY+VY)\\&=&PR+ST+VQ\end{array}$$

Comment: I also done in same way..But where we use the given condition that tangents are parallel to corresponding sides....and also how yu know that X,Y,Z are in between the sides ST,QV,PR ???

Comment: Well ... If you can prove something without using all the conditions from the problem, that makes your proof even stronger, not weaker. (You have proven a more general statement.) As for the ordering of the points... in most proofs in geometry I've seen, the questions of the ordering are usually glossed over - mostly because you are never given enough tools (e.g. axioms and theorems of ordering) that you could use in a rigorous proof. (See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#II._Order.) Thus I will dodge this question too.

Comment: (Cont'd) Having said that, I think you probably need to use a weaker statement (that the incircle is in the half-plane with edge $PQ$ which doesn't contain $A$, and similar for $B$ and $C$), which seems to be a consequence of those tangents being parallel. (For example, $Z$ is on the incircle, so $P$ is between $A$ and $Z$; similarly $R$ is between $B$ and $Z$, and from that one could mount a laborious axiomatic proof that $Z$ is between $P$ and $R$...)

Comment: Ok,I agree on second point..but disagree on first...even we proved this for more general case..there should some use of given condition in a particular case..and that I want to know because in similar type of  question maybe this knowledge helps..

Comment: @User12002 People who set up problems are just people, and fallible at that. They may have had another solution in mind, which required the tangents to be parallel. I can think of one such solution, but I like mine (and yours!) better!

Comment: Ok thanks , I understand the need of parallelism of Tangents with sides in your answers also...you said that P is between A and Z and R is between B and Z that is true  if tangent PQ is parallel to BC .. because if it doesn't then we can take P slightly down to Z and Q at top so it will become tangent with incircle...and similarly for others ...

Comment: Not quite - this is true "*if*" (but not "*only if*") there is parallelism. You can move the tangents quite significantly away from the "parallel" position (as long as the order of points does not change). The pathological cases arise when the tangent $PQ$ stops separating the point $A$ from the side $BC$ or a similar condition happens for the other two tangents. So, the order of points seems to be the thing that really matters here, and parallelism is one "sufficient" (but not "necessary") condition to ensure that order.

Comment: Yes ,I wanted to write, that because PQ is parallel to BC that's why P is between Z and A and R is between B and Z and so Z is between P and R and similarly for others...so hence question is over...!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $p$ and $h_a$ be the perimeter and the height of the triangle ABC, and $p_a$ and $h_a'$ be the perimeter and the height of the triangle APQ, respectively. Note the triangles APQ and ABC are similar. Then, with $r$ the incircle radius,

$$\frac{p_a}p = \frac{h_a'}{h_a}=1-\frac{2r}{h_a}\tag 1$$

Also note that

$$Area_{ABC} = \frac12rp = \frac12ah\implies \frac r{h_a} = \frac {a}p$$

where $a = BC$. Substitute into (1) to get

$$p_a = p- 2a$$
Similarly,

$$p_b = p- 2b, \>\>\>\>\>\>\>p_c = p- 2c$$

Thus,

$$p_a + p_b +p_c = 3p- 2(a+b+c) = p$$